# How do I sum 2 entry in thonny IDE

Tags: python

Basically I was trying to sum this 2 entry to make a calculator, but when the program sum, instead of a+b=c it print a+b=ab, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My telepathic abilities tell me that you are adding strings, not integers

[image]